# Validating Dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validation-engine

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitButton").click(function () { 
    if ( $("#formToSubmit").validationEngine('validate') == true) {
    $("#formToSubmit").submit();
    }
});
```

I am using the Validation Engine plugin for jQuery to validate forms on my site. I have a form that can get more text fields with the click of a button (js). The problem is once those fields are added they are not validated when content is typed and the user moves onto the next field, but after the user clicks submit. I want to know id there is a way to work around this and make the check dynamic again (checks as you fill it). above is the code for the init. please give me an idea on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the dynamiclly created fields have different ID attributes.

Comment: The dynamically created fields are text fields and are created with the form (which has the id attribute that is bentioned in the above code). Each field created has a different id. also, as i mentioned, when the submit button is clicked, the form is the validated and those fields are checked and if they are not filled the form is not submitted and the messages popup beside the fields. the problem is i want it to check dynamically instead of just when it is submitted. Any Ideas?

Comment: maybe checking the docs at: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine can help... good luck!